# passing :rails_env in capistrano to chef/cookbook/monit/mongrel.conf

Tags: capistrano, mongrel, monit, chef-infra

How do we pass the :rails_env vairable so that it recognizes what version we are into i.e. staging, production, demo

We are trying to get the :rails_env from the deploy.rb in capistrano to pass to cookbook and then to monit and then create a mongrel.conf file with different values for the environment (demo..production).  In mongrel.erb, we can pick up this variable/parameter and set the RAILS_ENV=xxxx

in the command line, want to specify what deployment we are doing -- cap chef:bootstrap production

this "production" sets the :rails_env in deploy.rb

Answer (score 1):

Set the environment variable in your shell (command line) before running your scripts and let your scripts pick up it's value i.e.:

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

You can access the value of RAILS_ENV using $RAILS_ENV in your scripts. Here's an example of somebody doing something similar at Pivotal Labs:

http://pivotallabs.com/users/steve/blog/articles/1286-chef-solo-is-great-you-might-not-need-client-server-

Comment: When monit runs the mongrel.conf, it does not pick up any environment variables. So the RAILS_ENV has to be set in the mongrel.conf. This is what we have in the .conf file now.        start program = "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/mongrel_rails start -d -p 3000 -c /home/ubuntu/xx/current -e demo -P /home/ubuntu/xx/current/log/nomad.3000.pid" as uid ubuntu and gid ubuntu.                                                    We want to make the "demo" to be configurable depending on what the cap command line sets

Comment: Okay, so somewhere in deploy.rb you have ":rails_env = demo", and then later on you can have your Capistrano task execute 'run "export RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"' ... then in your .conf file you could pick up the environment variable like this: start program = "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/mongrel_rails start -d -p 3000 -c /home/ubuntu/xx/current -e $RAILS_ENV -P /home/ubuntu/xx/current/log/nomad.3000.pid"

Comment: Slight correction. "cap chef:bootstrap rails_env=demo" on the command line would set :rails_env inside deploy.rb. I misundersstood your question. Does this help in any way?